# Python/MySqlDB - Query a database using raw_input and print the result

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, raw-input

I am trying to create a function that will query a database using a string (or part of a string) inserted via raw_input.
The database `PManDB` has only one table ( `accounts` ) with 3 columns ( `website, username, password` ).
Example: if in the column `website` I have the string `'www.website.com'` I want to obtain it inserting the values `'w'` or `'web'` or `'com'` in the `raw_input`.

The full code of the project is [here](https://github.com/marcogdepinto/PasswordManager/blob/master/main.py).
Below an extract without the function to print the database:

```
def SearchRecords(self):
            search = raw_input("Insert value to be searched in the DB:")
            db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "PManDB")
            cursor = db.cursor()
            sql = """SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE website LIKE %s"""
            data = (search)
            try:
                # Execute the SQL command
                cursor.execute(sql, data)
                print "The research has been made with success"
            except:
                # Rollback in case there is any error
                print "There is an error"
                db.rollback()
            # disconnect from server
```

The idea is to add a `cursor.fetchall()` after the `print` statement `"The research has been made with success"` using the following sintax

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
print result
```

Or to add a `for` loop

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
  print row[0]
```

But in both ways the code is not working.

Could you please help me understanding where am I wrong and why?

**EDIT1:** According to mata comment, I have added the error.
When I launch the application in PyCharm, introducing the modification proposed by mata, I receive the following error

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

The code updated is the following (still not working with the error above):

```
    def SearchRecords(self):
    search = raw_input("Insert value to be searched in the DB:")
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "studio", "PManDB")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = """SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE website LIKE %s"""
    data = ('%' + search + '%',)
    cursor.execute(sql, data)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print result
```

Comment: what do you mean with _"the code is not working"_? That's not a helpful error description.

Comment: Try `data = ('%' + search + '%',)` - without wildcards `LIKE` behaves the same as `=`.

Comment: Added an edit with the error and the outcome with your suggestion. Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved removing the db.close and the db.commit at the end of the function.